# Can't display my XML in HTML using script?

Tags: html, xml, json

Basicly, i've used

```
<script>
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "db.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    document.write("<table border='1'>");
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("desc")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

From w3school, to do something in my mind that is simple, and should work. But im suspecting that it needs to be on a server for it to work, either that or i can't use it properly. For the XML i've got several

```
<item>
<title>example</title>
<desc>description</desc>
<tags>Drama, Fantasy, Romance</tags>
<date>01 08 1982</date>
<img>img/nna.jpg</img>
<a_link>Link</a_link>
</item>
```

**Basicly, my question is. Does this work on my own computer, i'm suspecting that it won't let me due to some security setting and that i need to use json. Please enlighten me.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me on a server, but does not work just loading the same HTML page in the browser.

It won't work locally because .open is getting the xml file from the server (see W3 Schools [description](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)). When you run it locally there is nothing to serve the xml file.

Comment: Thank you, that was my suspicion. I guess i need to buckle down and buy a website to improve then, sucks.

Comment: All you need to do is run a website locally on your PC. I'm pretty sure that Visual Studio Express (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products#product-express-summary) also has the development webserver (Cassini) built in so that you can edit, run, check, edit... etc. Alternatively you can set up IIS.